# Nservicebus delayed retry with MSMQ

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

Can we enable delayed retries with nservicebus and MSMQ transport. 
When i do it it will throw a warning and move the message to error queue.

"Recoverability policy requested DelayedRetry however delayed delivery capability is not available with the current endpoint configuration. Moving message to error queue instead."

But according to nservicebus documentation it tells delayed retry can be performed if delayed delivery is supported. And i have below about delayed delivery.

"NServiceBus provides delayed deliver feature for transports that don't have native support for delayed message delivery, i.e. for MSMQ and SQL Server transports. "

```
 endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
        endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
        var messageProcessingConcurrency = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NservicebusMessageProcessingConcurrency"];
        endpointConfiguration.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(int.Parse(messageProcessingConcurrency));
        //configuring delayed retries
        var recoverability = endpointConfiguration.Recoverability();
        //recoverability.CustomPolicy(OrderRecoverability.CustomRetryPolicy);
        recoverability.Delayed(
            delayed =>
            {
                delayed.NumberOfRetries(2);
                delayed.TimeIncrease(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            });
        //no imediate retries
        recoverability.Immediate(
            immediate =>
            {
                immediate.NumberOfRetries(0);
            });
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<MsmqPersistence>();
        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        transport.Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.SendsAtomicWithReceive);
        var conventions = endpointConfiguration.Conventions();
        conventions
            .DefiningEventsAs(
                t =>
                    t.Namespace != null
                    && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Dodo.Fibre.Provisioning.Messages"));
```

---

As requested i have commented out the timeout manager disable line as below.
   // endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature();

But i can not start endpoint as i am getting below error.

```
2017-08-01 08:45:28.074 FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost Start fail
ure
System.Exception: The selected persistence doesn't have support for timeout stor
age. Select another persistence or disable the timeout manager feature using end
pointConfiguration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>()
   at NServiceBus.Features.TimeoutManager.Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext cont
ext) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\DelayedDelivery
\TimeoutManager\TimeoutManager.cs:line 34
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureInfo featureI
nfo, List`1 featuresToActivate, IConfigureComponents container, PipelineSettings
 pipelineSettings, RoutingComponent routing) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54f
ce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line 194
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(IConfigureComponents c
ontainer, PipelineSettings pipelineSettings, RoutingComponent routing) in C:\Bui
ldAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:
line 57
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildA
gent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\InitializableEndpoint.cs:line 60
```

Comment: Could you please share your endpoint configuration code? Delayed delivery is not the same as retries. You can configure the first/second level retries and the delay between each retry on MSMQ.

Comment: Added configurations.

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration code I can see that you have disabled TimeoutManager and that's the reason the delayed retries are not working as expected e.g.

```
endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
```

Any reason for that? While some transport like Azure ServiceBus / RabbitMQ have built-in delayed-delivery, MSMQ does not have that and that work is managed by the timeout manager.

Comment: Yes timeout manager is disabled because if enabled I can not start nservicebus host.  It complains that timeout is not supported in this transport.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense since you need it for MSMQ. See here: https://docs.particular.net/persistence/msmq/subscription#timeouts-persistence

Maybe add that exception message to the issue above, or open a support ticket with us so we can look into it for you.

Comment: I have edited and added the error when timeout manager is enabled.

Comment: ah that makes sense now :) The MSMQ "persistence" only allows storing subscription information and timeouts can not be stored there. You need a full-fledge persistance for that. The one suggested, if you have a database somewhere is either NHIbernate or native SQL persistence.

Comment: @srisanju There are other Persistence options available as well, have a look at this documentation page (menu on the right lists them all).

https://docs.particular.net/transports/

Comment: I know there are other persistence options but MSMQ is the one suites our solution best.  So are you telling me delayed retries are not supported in MSMQ now?

Comment: @srisanju MSMQ 'persistence' is something very specific, it can _only_ store subscription information, so if you use Sagas, Timeouts, etc you need a different persistence. Not to be mixed with the 'transport', you could still go with MSMQ for the transport and choose another persistence.